# How to Enable DEBUG log level for Junit Source code

Tags: debugging, junit5

I am trying to implement custom test class ordering with Junit 5.8.0M1.  It is not working. So, I want to enable DEBUG level logs for Junit code. Can someone help me on how to do that?. Looks like it is using custom logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 5 uses Java Util Logging.

For details, please see the official section of the [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle-logging).